# Genson selective use of useClassMetadata and addAlias

Tags: scala, polymorphism, genson

I'm using Genson in my project and have just hit the polymorphic types issue (trying to serialise classes of generic type X).

Genson handles this by inserting some class meta data [as explained here](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/UserGuide/#generic-types).

I'd like to use the 'addAlias' feature to make the json resilient to class refactoring changes but using this feature for my one polymorphic class seems to (as a side effect) turn on the 'useClassMetadata' flag for all other (non-polymorphic) classes.

This means to make my code resilient to class refactoring changes I need to add an alias for all my classes (and any future classes I might add) which is a pain and prone to be forgotten about and missed.

Is there a way in genson to turn on the inclusion of class meta data for just a small sub-set of classes and exclude it in the rest?

I've tried adding to the GensonBuilder 
      `.exclude("@class")
      .include("@class", classOf[X])`

but this had no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using useClassMetadataWithStaticType=false in the builder? From the docs http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Configuration/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @eugen but adding that flag seems to remove the class meta data for the generic typed classes too. I've created a gist if you have time to take a look that demonstrates my issue https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1d174ccdf03f89147ada6d71ae96f77d

Comment: Try without enabling the runtimeType serialization option as it will look at the runtime type instead of the compile time one. This is a bit suggested somewhat from the docs as we basically want to serialize metadata when runtime type != static type, but it's not very explicit, should probably update them.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @eugen but no joy I'm afraid. Still get no class meta data with useClassMetadataWithStaticType=false even with useRuntimeType=false. I created another gist with this combination of settings to demonstrate: https://gist.github.com/glidester/82886bf6eef37a5b965e3d0f6673a213

Answer (score 0):

So the best I've come up with so far is to create a separate instance of Genson with the same config as the original but with the additional 'addAlias' instructions for the polymorphic classes.

This is only really an option for me because I can select the appropriate Genson instance when serialising the polymorphic classes and select the other instance for the rest.

Not an ideal solution in my book so I'm open to better answers :)